# SQL Derived Table

Tags: mysql, sql, derived

I am new to SQL and really struggle just testing it out. My question is how do I derive data from one table to a new one keeping only specific data like:
-Real name
-Screen name

and also how do I create new variables using SQL. For example the Number of tweets that the person contributed.

Comment: Your second question is too vague.  You should ask another question, providing table layouts, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use `create table as`:

```
create table table2 as
    select RealName, ScreenName
    from table1;
```

However, you don't actually need to copy the data.  You can just use a view instead:

```
create view table2 as
    select RealName, ScreenName
    from table1;
```

Or, just put the logic into your query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `ur specific column`

INTO `newtable`

FROM `oldtable`;

[check here for more examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)